# Select odd/even child divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to dynamically create a "book" from code server-side.  That part's working fine, and generating output similar to the following:

```
<div id="pagesContainer">
    <div class="pageContent">
         <div>
             Page 1 content
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageContent">
         <div>
             Page 2 content
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageContent">
         <div>
             Page 3 content
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageContent">
         <div>
             Page 4 content
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageContent">
         <div>
             Page 5 content
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need to do, preferably using jQuery is add classes to the inner-most divs such as `page-left` or `page-right`.  For example, pages 1, 3 and 5 would get `page-left` while pages 2 and 4 would get `page-right`.  There may be more (or less) than 5 pages also.  I've tried using a bunch of different even/odd selector scenarios, but can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery passes in an integer when you iterate with `.each()`; can't you just use that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the :odd and :even selectors.

For example:

```
$('.pageContent:odd').addClass("page-left")
$('.pageContent:even').addClass("page-right")
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as it got me the closest.  I ended up using `$(".pageContent:nth-child(odd) > div").addClass("page-left");` to match my exact needs! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This should work.

```
$('#pagesContainer').children('.pageContent').each(function(index)
{
    $(this).addClass(index % 2 ? 'page-right' : 'page-left');
});
```

Demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/au8zA/).

Answer (score 3):

Try the `:odd` and `:even` selectors:

```
$('.pageContent:odd').addClass('odd');
```

You can also use `:nth-child` to take advantage of performance boosts because it's a builtin selector:

```
$('.pageContent:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.pageContent').each(function(i,t){
 var addClass = i % 2 == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even';
 $(t).addClass(addClass);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `nth-child(even)` as described here: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

```
.pageContent:nth-child(even) { /* Something amazing */ }
```

Comment: @ManseUK You're quite right. I read that he wanted to add classes to alternating rows and cut a corner to suggest CSS be applied directly to alternating rows without noticing that `CSS` wasn't tagged. Of course the class could be doing far more than just CSS!

Answer (score 0):

Use ':odd`and`:even` selectors

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
     $('.pageContent:odd').addClass('oddClass')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".pageContent:odd").addClass("oddPage");
$(".pageContent:even").addClass("evenPage");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?
http://jsfiddle.net/Sf7AD/3/

```
$('#pagesContainer > div:even').addClass('page-left');
$('#pagesContainer > div:odd').addClass('page-right');
```

Not that since the elements are 0 indexed, `:even` will counter-intuitively picks the first, third, fifth, etc element

From the docs
http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

> In particular, note that the 0-based indexing means that,
>   counter-intuitively, :even selects the first element, third element,
>   and so on within the matched set.