# Getting data from alternate select tags with php

Tags: php, html

Let say i have 3 select tags and an input tag in a form. i want that at any given time the user picks the first select option and one of the others.

```
<select name= "scholl">
    <option class="red" value="1"> 2013</option>
    <option class="blue" value="2">2014</option>
    <option class="green" value="3">2015</option>
</select>
<select name="depart">
   <option>Select Depart</option>
   <option class="red" value="one"> Aline</option>
   <option class="blue" value="two"> Bline</option>
   <option class="green" value="three"> Fline</option>
    </select>
 <h2>Or</h2>
<select name="coins">
 <option>Select Course code</option>
 <option class="red" value="1"> A</option>
 <option class="blue" value="2"> B</option>
 <option class="green" value="3"> C</option>
</select>

<h2>Or</h2>
<label>ID
 <span class="small">Enter Id</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" />
```

Example:

> option "2013" and option "Aline" 
>   or 
>   option "2013" and option "A" 
>   or
>   option "2013" and  "ID"

How can i write this in PHP?
Would really appreciate your help

Comment: you are trying to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911138/select-odd-even-child-divs

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) - Suggestion: either use the `onselect`-attribute to check client side (JavaScript/jQuery, for example), and/or change the form to one `select`-tag and use the corresponding option values to check for Dep. or Course.

Comment: @MartyMcVry the onselect will be it for my purpose but i really do not know how to do it. can you help pls?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a client side thingo, you have to do it via JavaScript.

You can  append javascript code to the `onselect` attribute in your select, where you check the required conditions are met!

Comment: i really do not know javascript. could you pls give me a sample code? that would really help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in PHP, this has to be done client-side in Javascript. Now, it can be done in plain Javascript, however, I'd suggest using something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), it will make it much easier for you as pure Javascript.