# Add Dynamic CSS Class MVC Razor View

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need help to alter 3 markups dynamically in MVC Razor view markup.  The html markup is as below

odd

```
<li class="active">
  <div class="widget widget-heading-simple">
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-4 center">
          <a href="" class="thumb">
            <img src="/@item.image" class="img" alt="Image" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 padding-none">
          <h5 class="strong text-uppercase">@item.title</h5>
          <div class="separator bottom">
          </div>
          <p>@Html.Raw(Html.Truncate(item.Text, 20, "...."))</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

even

```
<li class="active">
  <div class="widget widget-heading-simple">
    <div class="widget-body">
      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-8 center">
          <a href="" class="thumb">
            <img src="/@item.image" class="img" alt="Image" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 padding-none">
          <h5 class="strong text-uppercase">@item.title</h5>
          <div class="separator bottom">
          </div>
          <p>@Html.Raw(Html.Truncate(item.Text, 20, "...."))</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

I need to alternate or inject classes into divs for consecutive rows (ie odd and even)
eg for odd row

```
<div class="widget widget-heading-simple widget-body-white "> ,<div class="col-md-4 center">  and <div class="col-md-8 padding-none">
```

for even row

```
<div class="widget widget-heading-simple  widget-body-gray">,<div class="col-md-8 center">  and <div class="col-md-4 padding-none">
```

I have tried jQuery as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.widget:first').addClass('widget-body-white');
            $('.widget:second').addClass('widget-body-gray');

        });
  </script>
```

to no avail nothing happens and I do not know how to setup the  col-md- 4 or 8 requirements too.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You have nested div with class="widget", how can you set alternate grey and white bg color?

Comment: yes and I also have to alternate <div class="col-md-4 center">  and <div class="col-md-8 padding-none">  to <div class="col-md-8 center">  and <div class="col-md-4 padding-none">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.widget:odd').addClass('widget-body-white');
    $('.widget:odd').find('[class^=col-md]:first').attr('class','col-md-4 center');
    $('.widget:odd').find('[class^=col-md]:last').attr('class','col-md-8 padding-none');

    $('.widget:even').addClass('widget-body-gray');
    $('.widget:odd').find('[class^=col-md]:last').attr('class','col-md-4 center');
    $('.widget:odd').find('[class^=col-md]:first').attr('class','col-md-8 padding-none');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9bShX/46/)**

Comment: thanks if odd  is col-md-4 center  and .col-md-8 padding-none even becomes col-md-8  center and col-md-4 padding-none   The 4 and 8 exchage position between odd and even

Comment: I now have an idea have to remove 4 and add 8 and vice versa for odd and even but i want to give you the credit if you will edit your answer

Comment: Do you want to div 4 in odd .widget and div 8 in even? like this http://jsfiddle.net/9bShX/42/

Comment: the col-md alternates the image from left to right.  I have added the odd and even scenario for  the col-md -  to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the [odd and even selectors](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.widget:odd').addClass('widget-body-white');
    $('.widget:even').addClass('widget-body-gray');
});
```

You could also go with the [`nth-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
$('li.active:nth-child(odd)').addClass('widget-body-white');
$('li.active:nth-child(even)').addClass('widget-body-gray');
```

**EDIT**
If you need to add multiple classes, just edit the `addClass()` function accordingly.
From the documentation: `$( "p" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );`

So in your case:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.widget:odd').addClass('widget-body-white  col-md-4 center');
    $('.widget:even').addClass('widget-body-gray  col-md-8 padding-none');
});
```

Comment: thanks I also have to alternate <div class="col-md-4 center"> and <div class="col-md-8 padding-none"> to <div class="col-md-8 center"> and <div class="col-md-4 padding-none">

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.widget:odd').addClass("widget-body-white")
$('.widget:even').addClass("widget-body-gray")
```

reference [Select odd/even child divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911138/select-odd-even-child-divs)

Comment: thanks I also have to alternate <div class="col-md-4 center"> and <div class="col-md-8 padding-none"> to <div class="col-md-8 center"> and <div class="col-md-4 padding-none">

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.widget').filter(":odd").addClass('widget-body-white');
    $('div.widget').filter(":even").addClass('widget-body-gray');

});
```